# How do I send a post request to telegram API from C#?

Tags: c#, api, post, telegram

I have my telegram application with app's api_id and app's api_hash.

I used TLSharp library for implementing my own things. But now I need to use this https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.checkPhone telegram api method, but it's not implemented in TLSharp library!

I don't mind doing it all manually, but I don't know how!

I know how you send post requests in C#, example:

> var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/index", content);

but in this specific case I don't. Because I don't know:

1) what link should I use for sending post requests? I couldn't find it on the telegram's website.

2) what content should I pass there? Should it be just "(auth.checkPhone "+380666454343")" or maybe the whole "(auth.checkPhone "+380666454343")=(auth.checkedPhonephone_registered:(boolFalse)phone_invited:(boolFalse))" ?

So, How do I sent this post request to the telegram api? (NOT telegram bot api!)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use System.Net.Http like in this example (auth request to the server):

```
var user = new { login = "your login", password = "your pass" };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.RequestUri = new Uri("server route link"); // can be like https://a100.technovik.ru:1000/api/auth/authenticate
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
request.Content = content;
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
responseText.Text =  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: how is that even related to my question?
I ask for the telegram api link I should use and what should I pass there as arguments in order to use telegram's auth.checkPhone method

Answer (score 1):

I *think* based on a brief look, that it would be more along the lines of your second example, e.g.:

```
var phonenumber = "0123456789";
var content = 
    $@"(auth.checkPhone ""{phonenumber}"")"+
    "=(auth.checkedPhone phone_registered: (boolFalse) phone_invited:(boolFalse))";
var result = DoHttpPost("http://some.example.com/api/etc", content);
```

*(note: I've not listed the actual mechanics of an HTTP Request here, as that is covered in plenty of detail elsewhere - not least in the other current answer supplied to you;  `DoHttpPost()` is not a real method and exists here only as a placeholder for this process)*

And since the payload of this appears to indicate the exact function and parameters required, that you'd just send it to the base api endpoint you use for everything, but I can't say for sure...

I do note they do appear to have links to source code for various apps on the site though, so perhaps you'd be better off looking there?

Comment: Thanks. I searched again. There I have MTProto servers IP adresses. Is that what I have to pass as the api link? Or could it be?

Comment: not sure - don't you already have some sort of server address setting in the client you have that works?

Comment: Maybe I do, it is just that TLSharp has hidden those details from me